# How to just get the first Word in an environment variable? - batch / cmd

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I want to copy a file to a certain location, a Jenkins user will be asked to enter the project name and the batch file should just take the first word of the project name to enter in a directory path.

```
C:\Testfolder\%Project_Name%\Sub\
```

Now the project name looks like this:

```
Proj_1 Something Somethingelse
```

However I just want Proj_1 to be the folder accessed, like this:

```
C:\Testfolder\Proj_1\Sub
Not: C:\Testfolder\Proj_1 Something Somethingelse\Sub\
```

Is there any way to do that in batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to just get the first Word in an environment variable?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd) and adjust as necessary.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "Project_Name=Proj_1 Something Somethingelse"
for %%i in (%Project_Name%) do (
  set First_word=%%i
  goto done
  )
:done
echo C:\Testfolder\%First_Word%\Sub\
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
> test
C:\Testfolder\Proj_1\Sub\
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) - Conditionally perform a command several times.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two additional options for you that require less code.

The first one uses the natural delimiters of the `FOR /F` command.  This way you do not need to use a goto command to break out of the loop.

```
@echo off
set "Project_Name=Proj_1 Something Somethingelse"
for /F %%G IN ("%Project_Name%") do set "First_word=%%G"
echo C:\Testfolder\%First_Word%\Sub\
```

The second technique uses a neat trick with the `SET` command to break up the line based on a delimiter by replacing the delimiter with another set command. In my version I use a `SET` with the `/P` option so that any further words within the string are not assigned to a variable.

```
@echo off
set "Project_Name=Proj_1 Something Somethingelse"
(set "First_Word=%Project_Name: =" & set /p "=%" )<nul >nul
echo C:\Testfolder\%First_Word%\Sub\
```